# Modify the size of a pie chart with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I have run the following ggplot function :

```
    g <- ggplot(results_table, aes(x = "", y = Pct*100, fill = Criteria),width = 0.5) + 
         geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = Palcolor, fill = Palcolor) +
         coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0, direction = -1) +
         theme_minimal() + 
         theme(legend.position = "none", axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
               panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank(),
               axis.ticks = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank(), 
               plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0)) + 
         geom_text(aes(label = paste0(Criteria,"; ",sprintf("%0.1f", round(Pct*100, digits = 1)),"%")),
                   position = position_stack (vjust = 0.5, reverse = TRUE)) + 
        labs(title = gTitle) 
  }
```

and the pie is the following :

[image]

but it is too large. I would like to have a diameter smaller than the length of the second part of the title. How can I proceed ?

Comment: Could you add an example of your data?

Comment: The height of the output will control the size of the plot. If you want to program it so it's exact then I think you need to split out the second line of the title string (`gTitle`) and use that with `unit` as a `strwdith` and the `grid` library's `convertUnit` to calculate the height of your `ggsave` output...